# Forecasting an individual based on a representative group

Tags: forecasting, prediction

I’m trying to forecast demand for an individual based on historical data of many individuals, but I’m having trouble finding examples of this.

For example: I want to forecast the demand for a single person, Timmy, over the next few periods. Timmy is a relatively new customer, which means I don't have enough data to forecast based on his history alone. However, I do have the entire sales history of customers that look similar to Timmy.

I would like to leverage the historical sales data of this group to generate a forecast for Timmy, but I'm unsure how to go about it. Two options I've considered are:

1. Finding the mean value of the group over time, then forecasting using this mean value and applying the trend to Timmy. I haven't seen any examples of this before and am not sure how I would go about creating prediction intervals for Timmy's forecast.
2. Taking the individual sales histories for each customer in the group and aligning them relative to the fist payment of that customer - '1st payment', '2nd payment', etc. This removes the date component, so to predict Timmy's 3rd payment, I'd average all of the 3rd payments for the group. If Timmy's previous payments have differed from the group average, I'd have to scale the predictions accordingly. Again I haven't found any examples of this in practise.

I'm sure this must be a common problem, but I haven't found any resources so far. Are there any standard methods/practices for this type of forecasting?

Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated.